# Using dll plugins with Xamarin

Tags: c#, dll, plugins, xamarin

Is there a ways to use dll plugin files within an iOS or Android app? How would this be done? Is there a strategy to integrate the dll code into the mobile app?

Comment: You cannot load and execute (JIT) code on iOS that comes from outside the signed app, not allowed by Apple. You can on Android

Comment: Ok. But is it possible to - somehow - integrate the dll code into the app before sending it to apple?

Comment: ? What type of dll plugins are you talking about, CIL-Based assemblies?

Comment: Xamarin supports a very large ecosystem of third party code - via components, nuget packages, github, commercial vendors, etc.  But they have to be built for Xamarin - you cannot just any arbitrary .NET dll and expect it to work.

Answer (score -1):

This is not possible.  A compiled DLL is architecture dependent, meaning that if it can run in a desktop (x86 CPU) or cannot run on a mobile platform (typically an ARM CPU).

Comment: A CIL-based assembly (`.DLL`) is not ABI dependent.